# Call a variable in an if-statement inside a function

Tags: javascript, scope

Hello I've got the problem that I can't call the variable `imgNotSet` in my if-statement of the `openImage` function. My Question is do I need to give my variable another scope to call it or what did I do wrong?

```js
var imgNotSet = true;

function openImage() {
 if (imgNotSet) {
  var lightViewImg = document.createElement("IMG");
  document.body.appendChild(lightViewImg);
  document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute("src","imgplaceholder");
  var imgNotSet = false;
 } else {
  console.log("Img already set");
 }
}
```

Comment: "Call" it? You're assigning to it.

Comment: Show us how and when you are calling `openImage()` and where you expect `imgNotSet` to have a different value than it actually has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My Question is do I need to give my variable a special scope to call it

No. You are doing that already and that is the problem.

> ```
> var imgNotSet = false;
> ```

You've created another variable of the same name, but locally scoped to the function, here. Don't do that. Remove the `var`.